# Android List with Search not working

Tags: android, android-json, android-search

Problem is with the filter(Textwatcher) : My app, show 2 record when data matches the value present in the first name & 1 record when the record matches the value in lastname.

example: when I type M it will show 2 record for mary but when I type k it show 1 record of mary kom and 2 record of Karl plus json data(refer below json)

```
{
"details": [

        {
                "id": "01",
                "name": "Mary Kom",
                "email": "abc@uvw.in",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },


        {
                "id": "02",
                "name": "karl plus",
                "email": "pqrp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
]}
```

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     EditText inputSearch;
     ListAdapter adapter;

    // URL to get contacts JSON      
    private static String url = "http://www.abcd.in/api/details";   

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Enabling Search Filter               
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {
                // When user change the Text
                ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(cs);        

            }          
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                 
            }             
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable cs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }
        });

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();


    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] 
                    { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL, TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);                    

        }
}}
```

Comment: So whats the issue ? Are you getting exception or what ?

Comment: Good first post, but as Shahzeb point out you missed what your problem is. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, this will help you to rephrase your question so that you will get the potential answer.

Comment: @Vinay : We need more detail like adapter code.!! Because I think you need to override filter() method of adapter so..!!

Comment: Thanx for reply there is no bug at all, it works absolutely fine even the search works well but, the only problem is the when the search letter matches value in first name it show 2 record when there is just 1 record for the same. but when the search value matches the value present in the last name the display is perfect.

Comment: the above code is all i have written no filter class and no class with array adapter extends

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a default behavior of filter with  SimpleAdapter. what you wants to achieve, you need to implement your own custom filter.
See the Example here :- http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Change this code :
// Filter Class

```
 public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            worldpopulationlist.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
            } 
            else 
            {
                for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) 
                {
                    if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                    {
                        worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

> to

```
public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            worldpopulationlist.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
            } 
            else 
            {
                for (WorldPopulation wp : arraylist) 
                {
                    if (wp.getCountry().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).startsWith(charText)) 
                    {
                        worldpopulationlist.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

> It help you to achieve functionality.